# NoMethodError: .. .'admin?' while building Hartl RoR Sample_App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, methods, tdd

I've almost finished ch. 9 of Hartl's RoR tutorial, and I keep getting three errors on my test suite. I've gone through with a comb and everything SEEMS fine but clearly it's not.

Here's the ERROR logs:
https://gist.github.com/c7cf9884360c0b2bd05e.git

And here's my repo 
https://github.com/kfrz/sample_app

HALP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fyi- in the future please add the errors and relevant code right here, makes it easier (though it is really nice to get your full code on github!). Oh, for those coming here the ERROR gist is at

https://gist.github.com/kfrz/c7cf9884360c0b2bd05e

Allrighty, so after reading your error logs we are getting an undefined method error for "admin?"

```
ERROR["test_should_get_new", UsersControllerTest, 1.253923]
 test_should_get_new#UsersControllerTest (1.25s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:71:in `admin_user'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        app/controllers/users_controller.rb:71:in `admin_user'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
```

The critical line here is

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:71:in `admin_user'
```

and taking a look at the controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,  onlY: :destroy

#
#
#
#

   #confirm admin user
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

The problem is actually found at the `before_action`

You accidentally capitalized "Y" in `before_action :admin_user,  onlY: :destroy`

Change that `onlY:` to `only:`for proper access control w/ the before filter (and for admins only to have the destroy action) and you should be good to go!

Best,
TJ

Comment: Can't vote up but would if I could. Thanks for the tips all around and finding a typo that eluded my tired eyes for days. 

You're the best. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries dude, I was just going to point out the capitalization error (like I've done many many times before) but figured showing how to trace the error would help you and others! Have fun w/ the Hartl Tutorial... it rules!